# AWS Beanstalk and RDS Scaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I have use case query regarding scaling that I have a PHP Magento application running inside a Docker container on AWS Elastic Beanstalk backed by a AWS RDS (t2.micro) instance.

Now when I use Apache JMeter for load testing, I throw just 100 users in 10 seconds and my RDS instance goes down but Beanstalk instance remains fine. My question is how do I scale the RDS when an huge number of traffic comes?

Some said to me that you should use a at least medium instance for your RDS but how can we use the autoscale feature? Whether it exists in the case of RDS or not?

Some also said to use AWS RDS Read Replicas! I did not work with Read Replicas before but how do I load balance the traffic between different RDS read replicas, what are different ways and what if we need some low database operations? Will it scale in?

Any appropriate guidance will be appreciable. :)

Comment: There is no autoscale feature in RDS.

Comment: What should be most appropriate solution to tackle the problem?